# Create a bat file to run Android automated tests(Robotium) from command line

Tags: android, batch-file, automated-tests, ui-automation, robotium

I am working on Android automated testing. We would like to have a bat file integrated with MSBuild.exe. I have all the test cases created, however, I cannot get the bat file working properly.

Currently my bat file looks something like:

```
call android delete avd -n %avdName%
call android create avd -n %avdName% -t 8 --skin WVGA800 --force
call emulator -avd  %avdName%

call adb install %batPath%\..\%projectName%\bin\release.apk
call adb install %batPath%\..\%testProjectName%\bin\release.apk
call adb shell am instrument -w com.example.mobiletest/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

The idea is, on each run the bat file create a new AVD, launch it, upload APKs and run the tests. However it doesn't wait unitl the AVD finishes to launch and tries to upload the APKs, which gets me this error:

> Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?

How can I tell the bat file to wait until the AVD is fully launched?

Comment: The only workaround I know is, in you batch file, issue AVD lanuch command first, wait for a mount of time (says 30 second), then issue a adb install command. This is also the way android-maven-plugin used currectly to implement one of its standalone goal android:emulator-start.

Comment: @yorkw thanks for your help. I thought about doing that too. Is there a good way to sleep() in a bat file? I have found some workarounds like using ping doesn't sound good.

Answer (score 0):

adb wait-for-device install %batPath%..\%projectName%\bin\release.apk

Comment: Read [the manual](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#commandsummary) carefully, it only wait until device is connected, not OS is fully booted, using it with install would result error.

Comment: You might need to add a delay for a second or so after "adb wait-for-device", but it should be ready to install apps soon after coming online.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I use a hack like this

```
echo waiting...
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 100 -w 1000 > NUL
echo ...done
```

It waits for 100 seconds before continue. The AVD should be up and running in 100s.